# fadeout and fadeIn callback function in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i have three div with value first, second and third i want to fadeout them first and them fadein with delay function now i want that when my last div fadein then my all three div fade out. but my code in not working well

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('.fileianN').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
        $('.fileianLY').fadeOut().delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
            $('.fiuleHg').fadeOut().delay(3000).fadeIn(1000);

    })


</script>





<div class="duanNt">
<div class="fileianN">first</div>
<div class="fileianLY">second</div>
<div class="fiuleHg">third</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/axiwuz/4/edit)*

```
$.when(
  
    $('.duanNt').children().each(function(idx,el) {
        $(el).delay(idx*600).fadeTo(700,1);
    })
  
).done(function() {
    $('.duanNt').fadeTo(300,0);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/ 
http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/

P.S if you don't want to hide the `.duanNt` it self but only it's children than use: `$('.duanNt > div').fadeTo(300,0);`

Comment: my question is i want to fadeout all three div when my last div fade in but your code not doing so

Comment: @amit - Looks complicated after a first look but is the nicer way to handle same animations through multiple elements. Imagine having 100 DIVs to fadeIn and using the function concatenation. You'll get mad. You can use this little script for any amount of elements you need.

Comment: Great, I have never used .when thing :)

Answer (score 1):

Basivally you can use following code;

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

    $('.fileianN').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
        $('.fileianLY').fadeOut().delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
            $('.fiuleHg').fadeOut().delay(3000).fadeIn(1000);
                $('.duanNt').delay(5000).fadeOut();

    })


</script>





<div class="duanNt">
<div class="fileianN">first</div>
<div class="fileianLY">second</div>
<div class="fiuleHg">third</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use promise method to ensure that the animation is completed.

```
$('.fileianN').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
$('.fileianN').promise().done ( function () { $('.fileianLY').fadeOut().delay(2000).fadeIn(1000) ; } );
$('.fileianLY').promise().done ( function () { $('.fiuleHg').fadeOut().delay(3000).fadeIn(1000); } );
```

Now as you said, you want all divs to fade out when last one fades in . So,

```
$('.fiuleHg').promise().done ( function () { $ ('.fileianN, .fileianLY, .fiuleHg' ).fadOut(); } );
```

You can also fadeOut the main div `duanNt` instead of all three just like I did.
P.S. `.promise()` method came in jQuery 1.6

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.delay = function(duration) {
    $(this).animate({ dummy: 1 }, duration);
    return this;
};


$(function(){

    $('.fileianN').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
        $('.fileianLY').fadeOut().delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);
            $('.fiuleHg').fadeOut().delay(3000).fadeIn(1000);
                $('.duanNt').delay(5000).fadeOut();

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

There is already a ***callback function***. Which You can use like

```
$("element").fadeOut(1000, function() {
   //..callback
});
```

Your usage might be similar to this

```
$('.fileianN').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {   
     $('.fileianLY').fadeOut().delay(2000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $('.fiuleHg').fadeOut().delay(3000).fadeIn(1000);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the oncomplete callback function.

Just an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){ 
    $('.fileianN').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $('.fileianLY').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $('.fiuleHg').fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn(1000); 
        }); 
    }); 
}) 
</script>
```

Comment: like I said, it's just an example on how to use the callback function.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LJfVd/ you need to play around with the order of the fadein and outs..

Answer (score 0):

```
function fadeElements()
{
    var divs=$('.duanNt')​.​children();
    var i = 0;
    next();
    function next() {
        divs.eq(i++).fadeIn('1000');
        setTimeout(next, 500);
        if(i===divs.length) divs.delay(1000).fadeOut();
    };

}

fadeElements();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/feg3r/)